# Let $G$ be a group, then let $f :G\to G$ via $f(x) = x^2$. Now, is $f$ injective and/or surjective?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, then let $f :G\to G$ via $f(x) = x^2$. Now, is $f$ injective and/or surjective? To this end let $f(x)=f(y)$. Then
$$x^2 =y^2 $$
If we take a look at the group $(  \Bbb Q \setminus\{0\} , \cdot )$, the non-zero rationals with multiplication we find that $f(1)=f(-1)$ where obviously $-1=1$. This means that this $f$ is not injective for this group.

Now we will try to determine if $f$ is surjective. Let $b \in G$ be arbitrary. Then if $G$ is a group of order 2, i.e. the elements of $G$ are $\{e,b\}$ there is no element satisfying $f(x)=b$ because $b^2 = e^2=e$ in this case. So $f$ is not surjective on this group

My questions: Are these arguments correct? Is there a way to show these results without having to find specific examples where $f$ does not constitute an injective or surjective function? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the examples are correct. Even more simply, you could have used the cyclic group of order $4$ for both examples. Since the map can be surjective/injective, counterexamples are the natural way to go. However, you could prove instead that every group of even order has an element of order $2$ and conclude that if $G$ has even order, the map is neither injective nor surjective: it’s clearly not injective, since if $g$ is an element of order $2$, then $f(g)=f(1_G)$, and it’s not surjective because a map from a finite set to itself is surjective if and only if it’s injective.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This was very clear :)

Comment: @Slugger: You’re welcome!